# how can I each element of an array into one line instead of 6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a sort of cribbage game in Python, and it's actually going quite well. I've run into a problem though. Whenever I try to print the six 'cards' dealt to the player, it always prints them to 6 different lines. What would I need to use and how would I make it so they just print in one line right next to each other? My code is below:

```
#If a card has a 'T' on it, it is a 10
import math
import random
from cardArtGenerator import *

cardFaceSeparator = ''
def generateHeartFace(cardValues):
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" ┌───┐" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(f" | {c} |" for c in cardValues))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" | ♥ |" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" └───┘" * len(cardValues)))

def generateClubFace(cardValues):
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" ┌───┐" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(f" | {c} |" for c in cardValues))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" | ♣ |" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" └───┘" * len(cardValues)))

def generateDiamondFace(cardValues):
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" ┌───┐" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(f" | {c} |" for c in cardValues))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" | ♦ |" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" └───┘" * len(cardValues)))

def generateSpadeFace(cardValues):
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" ┌───┐" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(f" | {c} |" for c in cardValues))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" | ♠ |" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(" └───┘" * len(cardValues)))

deck = ['dA','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','dT','dJ','dQ','dK',

'hA','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9','hT','hJ','hQ','hK',

'sA','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','s8','s9','sT','sJ','sQ','sK',

'cA','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','cT','cJ','cQ','cK']

hand = []
separator = ''

def numberGenerator():
  for x in range(6):
    cardDealt = random.choice(deck)
    hand.append(cardDealt)
    deck.remove(cardDealt)

def cardArt(cardInput):
  if cardInput[0] == 'd':
    generateDiamondFace([cardInput[1]])
    
  if cardInput[0] == 'h':
    generateHeartFace([cardInput[1]])

  if cardInput[0] == 's':
    generateSpadeFace([cardInput[1]])

  if cardInput[0] == 'c':
    generateClubFace([cardInput[1]])

#actually prints the code cards, this is where I need help (line 61)
numberGenerator()
for x in range(len(hand)):
  cardArt(hand[x-1])

print(hand)
```

Comment: I don't see a way without kind of re-engineering your solution as you need to print both across and down over several calls. I would think about a slight rework of your display solution. If you want me to help get you started with that let me/us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit, but I think this code snippet fits what you want:

```py
import math
import random



deck = ['dA','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','dT','dJ','dQ','dK',

'hA','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9','hT','hJ','hQ','hK',

'sA','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','s8','s9','sT','sJ','sQ','sK',

'cA','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','cT','cJ','cQ','cK']


CARD_SYMBOLS = {"d": "♦", "h": "♥", "s": "♠", "c": "♣"}

def show_hand(cards):
    print("╭-----╮\t"*len(cards))
    print( "\t".join([f"|  {card[1]}  |" for card in cards]))
    print( "\t".join([f"|  {CARD_SYMBOLS[card[0]]}  |" for card in cards]))
    print("╰-----╯\t"*len(cards))

hand = []
separator = ''

def numberGenerator():
  for x in range(6):
    card_dealt = random.choice(deck)
    hand.append(card_dealt)
    deck.remove(card_dealt)

numberGenerator()
show_hand(hand)
```

The output would look like this:

[image]

Let me know if this is helpful!

Comment: I can't upvote this since I don't have enough reputation yet but this should work!

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @eric-lozano is a great one (I upvoted it :-).

I would tackle the problem in a slightly different manner though. I would definitely move the `print()` stuff out of method calls if I could.

This strategy is based on reshaping a your list of cards with face rows into a list of face rows with cards.

```py
import random

## ---------------------------
## Generate the display for a single card.
## You have this now but in multiple methods
## Note that we will only print() from our main
## ---------------------------
def get_card_face(card_key):
    card_suit, card_value = list(card_key)
    suit_display = {"h": "♥", "c": "♣", "d": "♦", "s": "♠"}.get(card_suit, "*")
    return [
        f"┌───┐",
        f"| {card_value} |",
        f"| {suit_display} |",
        f"└───┘" 
    ]
## ---------------------------

## ---------------------------
## Generatet the display for a hand of cards.
## Note that we will only print() from our main.
## ---------------------------
def get_hand_faces(hand):
    ## ---------------
    ## Get a list of the displays of each card.
    ## This will be a list of lists as each card display is a list of display rows
    ## ---------------
    hand_faces = [get_card_face(c) for c in hand]
    ## ---------------

    ## ---------------
    ## Reshape hand faces so that our list of lists changes from a list of
    ## cards into a list of rows. Note hand_faces now an enumerator.
    ## ---------------
    hand_faces = zip(*hand_faces)
    ## ---------------

    ## ---------------
    ## return a string with proper spacing and line breaks
    ## ---------------
    return "\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in hand_faces)
    ## ---------------
## ---------------------------

deck = [
    f"{s}{v}"
    for s in list("hdcs")
    for v in list("A23456789TJQK")
]
random.shuffle(deck)

user_hand = []
computer_hand = []
for _ in range(6):
    user_hand.append(deck.pop())
    computer_hand.append(deck.pop())

print("User Hand:")
print(get_hand_faces(user_hand))

print("Computer Hand:")
print(get_hand_faces(computer_hand))
```

This should give you something like:

```
User Hand:
┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐
| K | | 9 | | 4 | | 6 | | A | | 8 |
| ♥ | | ♠ | | ♣ | | ♥ | | ♠ | | ♣ |
└───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘
Computer Hand:
┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐ ┌───┐
| K | | 4 | | 9 | | 3 | | 4 | | A |
| ♠ | | ♦ | | ♣ | | ♣ | | ♠ | | ♦ |
└───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘
```